# Determining the encoding of an unknown image format

Tags: binary, encodings, api

I'm trying to reverse engineer a REST API and there is an endpoint that delivers images. Some of them are jpegs but other ones look like they're base64 encoded, except they don't appear to be, as they contain invalid chars such as & and -. If I "repair" the invalid chars I can base64 decode it, but it's just random binary data I can't discern anything from (does base64 have a checksum built in or can I base64-decode any string that has valid base64 characters?).

The data is around ~74 KB for an image I'm requesting in 500px width. Here is a bit of the content:

```
MAXe09nMdH7sLXdcCVfZhA1p3ll44Ye5vJABsCGRPlh4xej7NYAu9otU2xUns35mHcwVr1j12l9Mn2AsSP9RTZEjljoUGNzkCn5yshkPMGLBmyFgrI2PjRpme0UIFX9n/CF1K1FDbA8uhTqgqxLYV2DeA9LpG5hLSFPGlkKbGcsWlYa4YyqsbYtG9mg1knuzedm+kVWvPjUpN/WtypkypnaZKmUVnXh3jFgMxCOpWHLGX9QfptR331mte+pjS2n4Ot51EYvA2Bm0QxYoEZ8ZeV/W1UjkHw9L9PBH65NY/h1mL1s246/XHFsJT6eSnHTPFlILiT66cOVjJ+2T3LDidobQrDkamZi/+wwsugY5520lFrMUYvvtvyFEb
```

The API is sending a `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` header with the response.

Are there other common formats to encode binary data that I may not be aware of or does anyone have an idea what kind of data this could be?

Comment: "I suspect that the image is in a vector format" -- but you know where this image gets displayed, right?

Comment: Yes, the image is displayed in an iOS app. But of course I don't know what the app does with the data in order for it to be displayed.

Comment: I mean, can you determine if it *is* a vector or a bitmap? For example, if it's an interactive map and you can freely zoom in and out, it is most likely a vector image.

Comment: Good point. No I can't zoom in (without it getting blurry). So I guess it's probably a bitmap file (at least at display time) after all. It's strange that other images (photos) aren't in this format.

Comment: Why not RE the iOS app?

Comment: I have no experience with RE native apps and I didn't think I would have to if these darn images were something I could work with :). But I might have to consider taking it a step further.

Comment: If the client is an app the format may be obfuscated or encrypted. Even if it is a simple xor you can work hours on identifying the format. Therefore if you have access and the image format is not obvious reverse the client.